# QueryString in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need one small help. I have one django application already with me and everything is working fine. Now requirement is without making change in existing functions we want to pass urls parameter as a query string

```py
path('my-app/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),

# I added this line because I want to use dcid as a querystring
url(r'^my-app/(?:(?P<dcid>\w+)/)',include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
```

and my function is already written like this

```py
def orders_b2b_open_list_pageable(request):
```

We don't want to change in above functions but we want `dcid` in query string. How can we achieve that

I am doing this but when requesting like this

http://localhost:8002/my-app/1/orders/b2b/open/pageable/

I am getting following error

[image]

Thank You in advance

Comment: did you inspect `request.GET`?

Comment: No it is asking me that you need to change function like this `def orders_b2b_open_list_pageable(request,dcid):`

Comment: I really don't want to make dcid as a dependency for a function because this I will use in middleware

Comment: no, You don't have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to parse it in your urls.py, that would change your function signiture.

You can handle it in your view, by pulling the querystring value from the request:

```
def orders_b2b_open_list_pageable(request):
    dcid = request.GET.get('dcid', None)
    ...
```

Comment: This is not working it is asking me to add dcid in function parameter `def orders_b2b_open_list_pageable(request,dcid)` like this

Comment: I am getting this error `orders_b2b_open_list_pageable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dcid'`

Comment: What do you mean by "*This is not working "*? Did you try this snippet? I don't think you did

Comment: I have added screenshot of my error could you please have a look

Comment: Do you see any ***functional argument, named `dcid`*** in the `orders_b2b_open_list_pageable(...)` function?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, it's unnecessary to perform the querystring parsing in the url definition.  Simplify your url mapper and the `dcid` argument will not be passed to your view function.